# r.js with anonymous defines in self executing functions

Tags: javascript, requirejs, breeze, r.js

I am trying to optimize a durandal app into a single file using r.js via grunt and the durandal grunt task.

I am using js libraries that register with require inside a top level self executing function.  The code below is from the breeze.js source but the code is conceptually the same in knockout, moment + others

```
if (typeof exports === "object" && typeof module === "object") {
    module.exports = def();
 } else if (typeof define === "function" && define["amd"]) {
    define(def);
} else {
    breeze = def();
}
```

The problem is that the r.js optimizer obviously cant insert a module id into the anonymous define.

THis means that when the optimized build file is loaded, breeze is registered as a module without a name so it be 'required' into other modules.

Whats the best way to handle this ? (modifying the source to define('breeze', [], def) would work for example).

Maybe patch the code so it 'knows' its running with almond and registers with a configurable name ?

Comment: Did you actually try optimizing the code you show in your question with `r.js`. In my experience `r.js` is *quite capable* of finding the `define` call and adding the module name itself. There *are* some cases where it can't do it (for instance if the `define` already has the module name) but the code you show is not such case.

Comment: Of course I tried it and I cant get r.js to insert module name. Do you know for a fact it works ? (I could have something misconfigured)

Comment: Yes, I checked just before posting my comment.

Comment: Ok thanks - ill try it again on a simplified project - did you use any non default r.js settings ?

Comment: I used exactly this `r.js -o name=whatever out=foo baseUrl=js` where `whatever` is a module of mine in which I have a `define` call like the one you have in your question. (Make sure you are using a recent version of `r.js`. Maybe you are already doing so but some of the problems raised on SO evaporate once the OP upgrades to the latest version, so I thought I should mention it.)

Comment: I checked some of the other libraries with the same code and they do have module ids. I saw the breeze library and jumped to a wrong conclusion about how r.js searches for anonymous defines - must have something misconfigured for breeze. Thanks for taking the time to reply.